# Retrieving multiple datastore entities of the same kind in a transaction

Tags: go, transactions, google-cloud-datastore

I need to retrieve a list of items of one Kind where the key is the name of the entity.
Based on each item in the returned list I need to retrieve a list of items from another kind where the key is the name.
I think I need to run this in a transaction and I cannot find how to get multiple entities within a transaction without prior knowledge of a list of keys(GetMulti()). The code I am currently using follows with error handling removed for brevity.
Appreciate any assistance you can offer.

```
    q := datastore.NewQuery("Plans").Namespace(TargetNamespace).
        Filter("Status =", PlanActive)
    _, err := ps.DSClient.GetAll(tctx, q, &sponsorPlans)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    for spIndex, spItem := range sponsorPlans {
        updateMembers := false
        // for each sponsor plan get all the related active client plans
        q := datastore.NewQuery("ClientPlans").Namespace(hasu.TheConstants.Namespace).
            Filter("Name =", sponsorPlans[spIndex].Name)
        memberPlanKeys, err := ps.DSClient.GetAll(tctx, q, &memberPlans)
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
        for index := range memberPlans {
            memberPlans[index].CapSpend = 0
            memberPlans[index].RenewalDate = sponsorPlans[spIndex].RenewalDate
            memberPlans[index].MemberCap = spItem.MemberCap
            memberPlans[index].Services = spItem.Services
            memberPlans[index].Status = spItem.Status
            memberPlans[index].TotalLiveSessions = spItem.TotalLiveSessions
        }
        _, err = ps.DSClient.PutMulti(tctx, memberPlanKeys, memberPlans)
        if err != nil {
            return
        } 
}
```

Comment: Datastore transaction limits will definitely not allow you to do this. I am finding it hard to understand your use case, but can you get all the `Plans` like you are doing now, and update each `ClientPlans` in a transaction of its own?

Comment: If you not checked this out already, read about datastore limitations [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/limits#Cloud_Datastore_limits)

Comment: @powar Thanks for your response. The use case is basically two tables one has a list of templates. The other has a list of entries derived from the entries in the first table and represent a one to many relationship between each entry in the first table with x entries in the second. when the contents in the first table changes those changes must be propagated to the related entries in the second in a manner that maintains integrity

Comment: @powar I must be reading the limitations incorrectly of I am just don't get it. I am only using two 'kinds' with a seperate read from each kind. The volume at this point is exceedingly small but will grow and so I need to know if I can use a query with limits inside of a transaction. Again thanks for you response

Comment: Is [this documentation](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/datastore#hdr-Transactions) useful to you? It shows how to run a transaction without the `GetMulti` method.